# How to prevent modals from closing on table refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#liradata').load('../Tables/liradata.php', function(){
    setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    });
}
```

Basically I am wanting to update data in a table, however, I have a button (edit) that pops up a modal were you can change some values on the selected row. But when the above function is ran it closes the modal...

How do I have realtime data, without the refreshing of the page/divs?